# Proving that in a linear regression, if the confidence interval of a coefficient contains $0$, then the variable associated is not significant

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Suppose a linear regression setting with $n$ observations and $p$ explanatory variables. The hypothesis testing $H_{0}: \beta_{j} = 0$ vs $H_{1}: \beta_{j} \ne 0$ has the following test statistic at the level of $\alpha$:

$$ F_{calc} = \frac{\beta_{j}^2}{\text{Var}[\beta_{j}]} \sim F_{(1,n-[p+1])} $$

Then, for the same model, we can find confidence intervals for $\beta_{j}$ using the following pivotal quantity:

$$ t = \frac{\hat{\beta_{j}} - \beta_{j}}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[\beta_{j}]}} \sim t_{(n-[p+1])} $$

From which we can find the confidence interval at the level $\alpha$:

$$ C.I. : \left[ \hat{\beta_{j}} \pm t_{(n-[p+1])}^{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}\sqrt{\text{Var}[\beta_{j}]} \right]  $$

Now, just looking at the two statistics, we can see that under the hypothesis that $H_{0}$ is true, then the pivotal quantity and the F-statistic are very similar. Furthermore, we already know the result that relates the $t$ distribution and the $F$ distribution: if $ X \sim t_{(k)} $, then $X^2 \sim F_{(1,k)}$, which seems to be key in this problem. However, I can't find an argument to conclude that if the $C.I.$ of $\beta_{j}$ contains 0, then $X_{j}$ is not significant. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Show that the absolute value of the t-statistic is less than the same critical t value you see in the confidence interval formula.